# How to retrive data fro database in two columns?

Tags: php, sql

I am retriving data from table but it is just list( just one column). is it possible to make that list in two columns using html?

I think you do not need here example my code to answer, but if someone need, I will publish.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRNWd.png)

```
  <?php 

                        while ($UserNameRow = mysqli_fetch_array($UserNameResult)) {

                           echo "<tr style = 'border: 1px solid red;'>
                                <td>{$UserNameRow['username']}</td>
                              </tr>";

                        echo "<tr>
                                <td>{$UserNameRow['username']}</td>
                             </tr>";
                    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Always provide example code. *Always.*

Comment: Of course its possible to select data from two columns. `SELECT col1, col2 FROM table`. But no, you cannot use HTML for this - understand that HTML is just a markup language.

Comment: NOT select , i need to put on the page in 2 columns

Comment: So your're asking if its possible to put the data you retreive into separate columns in a table in HTML? Yes, it's very easy. Understand that its quite unclear for us to know what you mean without you providing concrete examples and your **actual code**.

Comment: can you provide an example???

Comment: please, describe your question a little bit more, like how your are trying to do your query, and how your are trying to display your columns, a picture is not enough, but your code will be very useful

Answer (score 0):

echo the same tuple inside the while loop.if you have only one column in your retrieve query just create another table row using html and inside that table row just echo all the other table definitions.
Example:

```
 <?php 

                    while ($UserNameRow = mysqli_fetch_array($UserNameResult)) {

                       echo "<tr style = 'border: 1px solid red;'>
                            <td>{$UserNameRow['username']}</td><td>{$UserNameRow['username']}</td>
                          </tr>";


                }
```

?>

N.B: just you have to echo the same row twice

Comment: if you can give an image or sample code i will be able to help you out.it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: is it still showing 1 row or you are getting any other type of error?

Comment: it is printing in one line repeating one record 2 times

Comment: sorry i thought you want two rows.I have changed my answer using your code